# 2 services on same hostname but different ports

Tags: port

I had 2 service on a server that run on 2 different ports. One of them on port 80 and another on port 3000. I want to address them like this:

`http://xxx.ttt.example`     : the one that run on port 3000

`http://xxx.ttt.example/zzz` : the one that run on port 80

what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a reverse proxy server such as nginx to achieve this. As port can be mentioned only in SRV records at DNS level, and most browser ignore this record while resolving a dns query for a http request.

The domain will point to a reverse proxy server and at proxy server you can configure where to pull response from based on the request.

Setup -

- Setup nginx reverse proxy server.
- point your domain `xxx.ttt.example` to the nginx server.
- In nginx config set a rule based on request uri fetch the response from port 3000.

Comment: "As port can't be mentioned at DNS level" Not true, they can with `SRV` records, the only problem is that the HTTP world does not use these records at all.

Comment: SRV records are used for very specific services eg. kebros ldap etc. I don’t think every web browser are designed to look for this information while resolving a domain for a http /https request.

Comment: Which is basically exactly what I said: ports can be mentioned at the DNS level (so your sentence is wrong in the generic sense) because of `SRV` records, BUT HTTP world does not use them, contrary to other services like IMAP, SIP, etc.

Comment: Updated the answer